# Junit throwing nullpointerexception array executeBatch

Tags: arrays, junit, prepared-statement, batch-processing

Trying to figure out why I'm receiving this nullpointer exception, appreciate any help!

(Connection and prepared statement already set up in inherited class)

Method trying to test:

```
public int insertPerson(int num, String word, List<Integer> lists) {
        int count = -1;
        try(Connection conn = mgr.getConnection(connName);
                PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(Queries.INSERT_PERSON);) {
            
            try {
                conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                
                
                for (Integer lis: lists) {
                    stmt.setInt(1, num);
                    stmt.setString(2, word);
                    stmt.setInt(3, lis);
                    stmt.addBatch();
                }
                
                int[] counts = stmt.executeBatch();
                count = counts.length;
                conn.commit();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                .
                .
                .
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Junit test:

```
    @Test
    void testInsertPerson() throws SQLException {
        int num = FakeDataGenerator.number(4);
        String word = FakeDataGenerator.randomString(5);
        List<Integer> lists = new ArrayList<>();
        lists.add(number(1));
        lists.add(number(1));
        assertNotEquals(dao.insertPerson(num, word, lists), -1);
    }
```

Receiving a nullpointerexception at this line:        int[] counts = stmt.executeBatch();

Comment: What do you want to test? If it's a unit test you should only try to test the smallest unit. In case of unittests you should mock the external calls and focus on only testing the method. So in your case I would expect mgr to be a mock, just like the returned Connection conn. Then you can do something like: `when(conn.prepareStatement(any()).thenReturn(preparedStatementMock);`
And verify the calls on the mocks to ensure your method does what you want.

Comment: I want to test the method insertPerson() to reach 100% coverage. I do not need to test/mock connection or prepared statement right now. Just trying to figure out this nullpointerexception.

Comment: Well `int[] counts = stmt.executeBatch();` throws the NPE, so stmt is null. `stmt` is returned from `conn.prepareStatement(Queries.INSERT_PERSON);` So that call `conn.prepareStatement(Queries.INSERT_PERSON);` returns null. That's what you should fix for this NPE.

Comment: I assumed that as well but why wouldn't the NPE happen earlier at stmt.setInt(1, num); for instance? Additionally when I changed int[] counts = stmt.executeBatch(); to just stmt.executeBatch(); I did not receive a NPE. I do need the count, otherwise I would just remove the array. Sorry I'm new to unit testing.